# PHP : Uploading multiple photos using <input type='file'> with same name

Tags: php, file-upload

I m trying to upload multiple photos using

```
<input type='file'>
```

with same name to the input element like,

```
<?php
$remainGal  =   $maxGallery-$totalGallery;
if($remainGal>0){
?>
<div class="businessSPGItems">
<form name="addBusinessGallery" method="post" action="businessservices.php#messageGallery" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="businessID" value="<?php echo $businessID;?>" />
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$remainGal; $i++){
?>
<input type="file" name="filePhotos[]" style="margin-top:5px;" tabindex="<?php echo $i+5; ?>" /><br />
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="btnAddGallery" value="Add" style="margin-top:10px;" tabindex="<?php echo $i+5; ?>" />
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

But the problem is when i m taking the total count of the file element it always shows 5...
ie.,

```
<?php 
$photos     =   $_FILES["filePhotos"];
echo count($photos);
?>
```

So i could not upload more than 5 photos at a time....
i dont know i m doing the correct method..
help please,,
thanks...

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered a more advanced upload control like PLUpload?

Comment: I m new in PHP, i dont heard about that..

Comment: Look at the output of `var_dump($photos);` instead.

Comment: I guess the value of `$remainGal` is set to 5. Apparently, there will be 5 `file` HTML controls in your HTML. I suggest you use some advanced file upload input controls like PLUpload, SWFUpload.

Comment: @SherinJose: They are easy to integrate. just follow their documentation.

Comment: @jimp The var_dump shows the details of all files in the form...it works..but how can i count the number of files in the form..

Comment: @SherinJose `count($_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"])` should work. If uploading nothing throws a notice, you could wrap it in a conditional: `if (empty($_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"]) == FALSE) { count($_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"]); }`

Comment: @jimp ..now it is counting in the correct way...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$_FILES["filePhotos"];` will have an array of values.

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

> ...the arrays $_FILES['userfile'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'],
>   and $_FILES['userfile']  ['size'] will be initialized...
>   Each of these will be a numerically indexed array of the appropriate
>   values for the submitted files.

```
$_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"][0];
$_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"][1];
$_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"][2];
$_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"][3];
$_FILES["filePhotos"]["name"][4];
```

Also note that there is an upload limit config value.
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

> The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously.
>   Starting with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not
>   count towards this limit.

It defaults to 20.