# cant able to insert multiple images with multiple inputs in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I can't able to insert multiple images with multiple inputs in codeigniter, I tried so hard, but can't able to get images.

Below is my code. Can any one guide me i right direction?

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="item_img[]">
<input type="file" name="item_img[]">
<input type="file" name="item_img[]">
<input type="file" name="item_img[]">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
if($this->input->post('save')=='save')
{
    $count = count($_FILES['item_img']['size']);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {

        $config['upload_path'] = './img/items/';
        $config['allowed_types']= 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $count = count($_FILES['item_img']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$i];  
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $names='img/items/'.$data['file_name'];


        $insertdata2=array( 'i_img'=>$names, 'createdon'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
        $this->model->insertData('item_info_master',$insertdata2);

    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function insertData($table,$data)
{
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the images form one input

```
<input type="file" name="item_img" multiple>
```

and you can retrieve it form php using $_FILES

Comment: I have one or more inputs in my system with add functionality.

Comment: then remove big bracket from input name i.e. []

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues.  I would first recommend switching your input to this:

```
<input type="file" name="item_img" multiple="multiple" />
```

If you can't do that, then you need to handle your PHP loop differently in the controller to get those images.  Here is a question/answer to help with that, **[Uploading multiple photos using  with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633830/php-uploading-multiple-photos-using-input-type-file-with-same-name)**.

There are several things you need to adjust in your controller besides the loop.  For starters, `$_FILES['item_img']['size']` is getting the size of the file itself (ex: 5MB), not the number of files.  So that count variable will never work.

You also aren't loading the upload library and config correctly.  Check out this question/answer, **[Upload multiple files in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377218/upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter)**, for a good example of how to load the config, and then process multiple images.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" name="gallery[]" multiple>
```

and php code:

```
if(!is_dir("uploads/gallery/".$id."/")) {
  mkdir("uploads/gallery/".$id."/");
}
foreach($_FILES['gallery']['name'] as $key=>$val){
  //upload and stored images
  $target_dir = "uploads/gallery/".$id."/";
  $target_file = $target_dir.$_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key];
  $type = 'image';
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key],$target_file)){
    $this->model->addGallery($id,$target_file,$type);
    //$images_arr[] = $target_file;
  }
}
```

Your welcome